# Automake: overwriting DEFAULT_INCLUDES

Tags: autotools, autoconf, automake

I would like the option to redefine the set of includes used by automake either at configure time or at compile time.  I know the following works:

```
make DEFAULT_INCLUDES= CPPFLAGS="-I. -I/home/development/trunk"
```

My question is whether there's a better way to override DEFAULT_INCLUDES?

The solution has to work for the entire project which is somewhat large.  A solution using configure.ac would be acceptable, but it must be optional.  In other words, I don't think using nostdinc with AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE will work because there doesn't seem to be a way to call the macro conditionally.

Comment: Not really.  We've been using nostdinc because we haven't found any other way that fits our needs.  As the question says though, nostdinc doesn't really do what we want either.

Answer (score 4):

If `configure.ac` contains

```
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([foo/config.h])
```

Then the generated `Makefile.in` will contain

```
DEFAULT_INCLUDES = -I.@am__isrc@ -I$(top_builddir)/foo
```

Using just `AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])` therefore will always cause `-I$(top_builddir)` to be appended as last include search path.

This is to the accommodate

```
#ifdef HAVE_CONFIG_H
#include "config.h"
#endif
```

in your source code.

I'd argue that the top_builddir should *only* contain that `config.h`; and your application should only have a single `configure.ac` and hence a single `config.h`,
so if an application does `#include "config.h"` it would either not compile or find the `config.h` in the top_builddir.

Then there still is the leading `-I.` however. I consider that one a bit dubious
myself because it seems to be needed to pick up generated header files from the object directory (the build directory), only -- after all, while else would there be anything in the *build* directory to include? But since an application must be able to be compiled also when it is compiled in the source tree itself, in which case the builddir == srcdir, it automatically includes the source directory. In order to make the two cases at least equivalent one MUST (then) also include the source directory when the build directory and the source directory are NOT the same.

This is taken care of with the `@am__isrc@` that expands to `-I$(srcdir)` if and only if the build directory and source directory are not the same (this is just to avoid having two `-I. -I.` after another).

Assuming that you either do not have any generated header files in your source directory (you could put them somewhere else) then this include would only "get in the way" when you include headers that ARE in your source directory but you don't want to include them. That seems rather broken if you ask me... Namely, if you have

```
#include "foo.h"
```

in your source file, and surely that source file *should* be in the srcdir (this is why you should *not* use 'source files' in subdirectories - aka `FOO_SOURCES = subdir/foo.c` but use `SUBDIRS = subdir` instead and compile `foo.c` in `subdir`), that include will look in the srcdir *anyway* because of the double quotes (such includes are always first looked for in the path of the including file).

Nevertheless, you can just override this define by adding

```
DEFAULT_INCLUDES =
```

To your `Makefile.am`. Even when you add that at the very top of a `Makefile.am` it will still end up below the first define and override it.

Or, for that matter, you could do:

```
DEFAULT_INCLUDES = @my_default_includes@
```

and set it to whatever you want (using `AC_SUBST(my_default_includes)` in your configure.ac).

Answer (score 0):

[Autoconf's manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf.html#Site-Defaults) suggests using a `config.site` file.

Comment: Can you give an example?  I don't think that's the right way to use the config.site file and I don't think it would accomplish what I asked for.